# How to get username from URL

Tags: php, regex

I would like to pull the username from a Youtube URL such as:
https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbffYWYFQqR25X_d8b5Q_PQ

The username is in this case: UCbffYWYFQqR25X_d8b5Q_PQ

Could someone help me out with the expression so that I can use it in the following format:

```
$url = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbffYWYFQqR25X_d8b5Q_PQ";
$re = "<EXPRESSION GOES HERE>";

preg_match($re, $url, $matches);

$username = $matches[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match everything after the "youtube.com/channel/" with this RegEx:

`/(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/channel\/([\S]+)/`

*Note that this RegEx allows for the domain "youtu.be" as well, as this is used as an alternate link for videos sometimes.*

I would probably try something like this instead though, to check both requirements:

```
if (!preg_match("/(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)/",$youtubeUrl)){
echo "This is not a YouTube link!";
} else if (!preg_match("/\/channel\/([\S]+)/",$youtubeUrl)){
echo "This is not a valid YouTube channel!";
} else {
echo "Success!";
}
```

Comment: Great this works, is there a way to check if the URL is Youtube at the same time so that they don't type in something else?

Comment: Yep, check my edit.  Please accept if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

`UCbffYWYFQqR25X_d8b5Q_PQ` is the last alphanumeric characters in the url. You can use the following regular expression:

```
/\w+$/
```

BTW, `$matches[1]` should be `$matches[0]` unless you use a capturing group (`/(\w+)$/`):

```
$url = "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCbffYWYFQqR25X_d8b5Q_PQ";
$re = "/\w+$/";

preg_match($re, $url, $matches);

$username = $matches[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$parts = explode('/', $url);
$username = array_pop($parts);
```

*Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.*

If you insist on using a regexp, which also checks whether you're really on youtube.* or youtu.be, use:

```
$re = '#youtu\.?be.*/([^/]+)$#';
```